# Google App Engine Task Queue

Tags: performance, google-app-engine, task, task-queue

I want to run 50 tasks. All these tasks execute the same piece of code. Only difference will be the data. Which will be completed faster ?

a. Queuing up 50 tasks in a queue

b. Queuing up 5 tasks each in 10 different queue

Is there any ideal number of tasks that can be queued up in 1 queue before using another queue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rate at which tasks are executed depends on two factors: the number of instances your app is running on, and the execution rate of the queue the tasks are on.

The maximum task queue execution rate is now 100 per queue per second, so that's not likely to be a limiting factor - so there's no harm in adding them to the same queue. In any case, sharding between queues for more execution rate is at best a hack. Queues are designed for functional separation, not as a performance measure.

Comment: It is a hack, but distributing tasks across queues has other value too.  I sometimes see one queue slow down for no apparent reason while others continue at a high rate.  Of course, unless your dealing with a large number of tasks this is probably a non-issue.

Answer (score 0):

Queue up 50 tasks and set your queue to process 10 at a time or whatever you would like if they can run independently of each other. I see a similar problem and I just run 10 tasks at a time to process the 3300 or so that I need to run. It takes 45 minutes or so to process all of them but the CPU time used is negligible surprisingly.

Answer (score 0):

The bursting rate of task queues is controlled by the bucket size.  If there is a token in the queue's bucket the task should run immediately.  So if you have:

```
queue:
- name: big_queue
  rate: 50/s
  bucket_size: 50
```

And haven't queue any tasks in a second all tasks should start right away.

see http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/queue.html#Queue_Definitions for more information.

Splitting the tasks into different queues will not improve the response time unless the bucket hadn't had enough time to completely fill with tokens.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add another factor into the mix- concurrency. If you have slow running (more than 30 seconds or so) tasks, then AppEngine seems to struggle to scale up the correct number of instances to deal with the requests (seems to max out about 7-8 for me).

As of SDK 1.4.3, there's a setting in your queue.xml and your appengine-web.config you can use to tell AppEngine that each instance can handle more than one task at a time:

```
<threadsafe>true</threadsafe> (in appengine-web.xml)
<max-concurrent-requests>10</max-concurrent-requests> (in queue.xml)
```

This solved all my problems with tasks executing too slowly (despite setting all other queue params to the maximum)

[More Details (http://blog.crispyfriedsoftware.com)](http://blog.crispyfriedsoftware.com/post/7718668518/appenginetaskqueueproblems)